# Add a dictionary's values in a mongo aggregate call

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

**Background**

I have a javascript dictionary that I make like this:

```
var Jidcs = {}
var mycursor = db.tags.find({"tagkey":"color"})
while (!mycursor.isExhausted()) {
    colors = mycursor.next()
    Jidcs[colors._id]= colors.tagvalue
}
```

I have a mongo aggregate that has items where one attribute matches the key in `Jidcs`. So, these items all have a "foreign key" to the value in the dictionary.

So, every item has a differing id that matches a color value in the dictionary. I want to group by these values. My end goal is to list the total item cost counts for items that have each color. $10 in pinks, $20 of reds etc.

**Question**

How do I "append" the value in the dictionary to the object within an aggregate call?

**Notes**

This works for what I want but is incredibly slow:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match: {"tagidlist": {$in:Jids}}},
    {$unwind: "$tagidlist"},
    {$lookup: {"from": "tags", "localField": "tagidlist", "foreignField": "_id", as: "TagDetails" }},
    {$unwind: "$TagDetails"},
    {$group: { _id: "$TagDetails.tagvalue", cost: { $sum : "$cost"}}}
]);
```

**Edit 1:**

`tagidlist` is an array of ids. 10 of them. These ids correspond to the tags collection

items collection object sample:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d2f8762f50da20c900dbd1d"), "period" : 201812, "cost" : 3, "tagidlist" : [ 126517, 7293, 148653, 79309, 16261, 147891, 83787, 154593, 97223, 88283 ] }
```

tags collection object sample

```
{ "_id" : 200000, "tagkey" : "color", "tagvalue" : "orange" }
```

Comment: What does `tagidlist` contain? could you show some sample documents

Comment: @Ashh I have added some info in Edit 1

Comment: Removing second might will help you some. But you have to swallow that $group stage is one of the blocking stage